# dotnet new could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I wanted to do something with Avalonia in C#, but if I run dotnet new avalonia.app it throws this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path '/home/af2111/Schreibtisch/Coding/C#/Avalonia UI'.
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserEntries(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Utils.PhysicalFileSystem.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(String directoryName, String pattern, SearchOption searchOption)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.Scanner.DetermineDirectoriesToScan(String baseDir)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.Scanner.Scan(String baseDir, Boolean allowDevInstall)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.TemplateCache.Scan(String installDir, IReadOnlyList`1& mountPointIdsForNewInstalls, Boolean allowDevInstall)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Edge.Settings.SettingsLoader.RebuildCacheFromSettingsIfNotCurrent(Boolean forceRebuild)
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.ExecuteAsync()
at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.CommandParsing.NewCommandInputCli.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<OnExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I already installed the Avalonia Templates once, but I meanwhile deleted the folder.
The path that's shown in the error message is the one to the folder that I deleted.

I'm running Manjaro Linux and using dotnet core 3.1.108.

Comment: Did you try to simply reinstall the templates with `dotnet new -i Avalonia.Templates`?

Comment: thank you, that was the problem